# Huawei P9 Lite recreates whole Application and Service when task is removed

Tags: android, service, android-service

I've encountered an interesting and annoying issue while testing my app on Huawei P9 Lite - When running a `STICKY Service` (`START_STICKY` flag returned from `onStartCommand`) and later removing the task from recent tasks causes the `Application` to recreate itself along with the `Service`. It means that `Application`'s `onCreate` method is called while the previous instance of the application becomes `[DEAD]`.

I have disabled system optimizations and closing high energy consuming applications in the settings according to [dontkillmyapp.com](https://dontkillmyapp.com).

I have created a testing app for this issue and I am logging every overrideable method call.

Here is how the application workflow looks:

```
*** Starting the service ***
I/MainService: onCreate
I/MainService: onStartCommand

*** Opening recent apps ***
I/MainActivity: onPause
I/MainActivity: onStop
I/App: onTrimMemory
I/MainService: onTrimMemory

*** Removing my app from recents ***
I/MainActivity: onDestroy
I/MainService: onTaskRemoved
*** app becomes [DEAD] ***


*** New instance of my app and service is recreated (actually 3 times???) ***
I/App: onCreate
I/MainService: onCreate
I/MainService: onStartCommand
I/App: onCreate
I/MainService: onCreate
I/MainService: onStartCommand
I/App: onCreate
I/MainService: onCreate
I/MainService: onStartCommand
```

Now for some this issue wouldn't be such big of a deal since the service might do some work that is not really sensitive to service restarts. In my case, in an actual application, the services maintains a connection with a *Bluetooth Low Energy device* which after a certain numbers of forced reconnections might stop responding.

Additionally, so far it seems like an issue that is happening only on this Huawei P9 Lite device - other Chinese manufacturers like Xiaomi don't do this to my app and service.

Also, I have encountered an application that is immune to this behavior, so I know that there has to be a workaround to this issue, but yet it is unnknown to me.

If You have encountered a similar issue, not necessarily on a Huawei phone, and had tackled it - please help.

Here are the main code snippets of the application - they are not any special, it is pretty standard way of creating a foreground service:

**MainActivity**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val mainServiceIntent: Intent
        get() = Intent(application, MainService::class.java)
    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate")

        ...

        prepareServiceButton()
    }

    private fun prepareServiceButton() {
        binding.buttonService.setOnClickListener {
            if (isServiceRunning) stopMainService() else startMainService()
        }
    }

    private fun startMainService() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(mainServiceIntent)
        } else {
            startService(mainServiceIntent)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**MainService**

```kotlin
class MainService : Service() {

    ...

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        Log.i("MainService", "onCreate")

        ...
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.i("MainService", "onStartCommand")

        updateNotification()
        ...

        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun updateNotification() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForeground(1, notification)
        } else {
            notificationManager.notify(1, notification)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**App**

```kotlin
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        Log.i("App", "onCreate")

        ...

        createNotificationChannel()
    }

    ...
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.taskremovingtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        ... >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MainService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Different manufacturers have different approaches to this. Also different versions of Android behave differently. You can try putting your `Service` in a separate OS process (different OS process from your activities). This may insulate it from being killed when the OS process containing the activities is killed.

Comment: Thanks for help! I've added `android:process=":mainServiceProcess"` to the `<service>` tag in Manifest. Unfortunately this does not prevent the application and the service from restarting like I've described in the question.

Comment: Well, there isn't any foolproof way to prevent Android from killing a process. That's just the way it works.

Comment: I have an app that accomplished exactly that on the Huawei device though... So there has to be a way.

Comment: Well, if that app has system permissions or is otherwise signed or prioritized by the manufacturer, then it might be in a whitelist of apps that shouldn't be killed. But you will not be able to get that unless you make a deal directly with the manufacturer.

Comment: No, the app doesn't have system permissions nor is it prioritized by the manufacturer. I'm sure of that since I got to talk with the app developer himself, but I didn't get to know the way he made service work like I want on Huawei device. I just want to say, that there is a way to create such service on that device and I'm just hopeful that there  is someone here that just happens to have overcome this problem and can help.